# Pick a specific "route" in a intersection type

Tags: typescript

I am working with next.js a library that doesn't export all of its declared ts interfaces/types which means that I sometimes need to get the types by selecting them from an intersection type, an example:

```
interface Object {
  src: object
  prop: string
}

interface String {
  src: string
  prop: number
}

type Combined = Object | String

function func1(props: Omit<Combined, 'src'>) {
  func2({src: 'str', ...props})
}

function func2(props: Combined) {}
```

Now in my case, I don't have access to the Object, String interfaces only to the Combined type in my func1 (Let's pretend that I cant access them as well in this example). But using the `Combined` type on the `props`parameter results in this error: `Argument of type '{ prop: string | number; src: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Combined'`. Because there is a possible combination in which the props.prop and src are both strings. You would think adding a typecheck like this into the func1 would help:

```
if (typeof props.prop === 'number') {
    func2({ src: 'str', ...props })
  }
```

It indeed doesn't help and ts returns the same error even tho it clearly should now know that props.prop cant be string which means that it can only follow the String interface in the intersection Combine type. So how do I solve this? How do I say to ts that I want to pick the String interface in the intersection Combine type so that I can just assign it tho the props parameter and not have to make the distinction down the road through type checks? Is there any utility-type that I missed that could achieve this and pick one of the interfaces from the intersection?

Comment: pls share `combined` function

Answer (score 0):

Does this example work for you:

```js
interface Object2 {
  src: object
  prop: string
}

interface String2 {
  src: string
  prop: number
}

type Combined = Object2 | String2

function combined<T,>(arg: Omit<Combined, 'src'> & T) { }

function func1(props: Omit<Combined, 'src'>) {
  combined({ src: 'str', ...props })
}

function func2(props: Combined) { }
```

Comment: Sorry I called the combined function for some reason - I was suppose to call func2 so no this will not work because the func2 is a nextjs image component that I cant change. Problem being that you can pass a url or a file into it and there is some extra logic if you want to load a external image from a url. So I wanted to simplify it and put it in a seperate component but I cant since I would have to use a any type as the argument which would be very messy. So my only option is to just enclose the extra logic in another utils function not in a component which isnt a solution either.